# Wrong result with simple fql status

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, status

I'm testing this fql multiquery

`"status":"SELECT status_id,time,message,place_id,source,uid FROM status WHERE uid = \''.$pageID.'\' AND status_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM #query1))",`

This must return a list of status by selected "user" ($pageID) on selected status_id

The result is wrong, I get the same result of

`"status":"SELECT status_id,time,message,place_id,source,uid FROM status WHERE status_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM #query1))",`

Where the second query print 27 status with many different UID, the first quety print the same 27 status but all with the same UID ??

any idea / suggest ??

**update** : i paste here full multiquery used

`$multiQuery =  '{
"query1":"SELECT object_id,post_id,object_type FROM like WHERE user_id = me() limit 200",
"status":"SELECT status_id,time,message,place_id,source,uid FROM status WHERE (uid = \''.$pageID.'\' AND status_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM #query1))",
"photo":"SELECT object_id,created,owner FROM photo WHERE owner = \''.$pageID.'\' AND object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM #query1)",
"link":"SELECT created_time,owner FROM link WHERE owner = \''.$pageID.'\' AND link_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM #query1)"
  }';`

Comment: Well, what is query1?

Comment: Hi Tommy, inserted on first post